# How to write data from a CSV directly to an Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, xml, list

Right now I'm writing an XML file to an CSV file and I want to write that CSV file immediately to an Excel file without re-opening or using an other `with-open` statement. Is that possible?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from glob import iglob
from os.path import isfile, join
from csv import DictWriter
from collections import ChainMap

xml_root = r"C:\data\Desktop\Blue\XML-files"
pattern = "xmlfile_*"
data = ChainMap()
for filename in iglob(join(xml_root, pattern)):
    if isfile(filename):
        tree = ET.parse(filename)
        root = tree.getroot()
        temp = {node.tag: node.text for node in root.iter() if not node}
        data = data.new_child(temp)

with open(join(xml_root, "data.csv"), "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = DictWriter(f, data)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data.maps[:-1])  # last is empty dict
```

I want to use any kind of one-liner to immediately write the created csv file into a excel file.

Comment: As trick, you can open your .csv file with Excel. Otherwise, you have should use a python module that handles the .xls/.xlsx format

Comment: @Kaz, when I open it as an Excel file I get everything within before the first comma as one column.

Comment: Open it in Excel as a CSV file - use delimiters in the file commas or tabs as you wish. I transfer lots of data with CSV files, no problems.

Comment: @Al-Andalus maybe your separatos is not correctly set in Excel/python

Comment: This may help https://support.affinity.co/hc/en-us/articles/360044453711-How-to-open-CSV-files-with-the-correct-delimiter-separator

Comment: Why generate a CSV text file if you really want an Excel file? Use [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) to generate the Excel file you want directly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos could you show me how to do that ? I have a dictwriter which makes things quiet complex... You would really help me :(

Comment: I already posted the link to the docs. You didn't show what your data looks like so it's impossible to post a concrete example - what does `data` contain? If it's an array you could use the [simple loop in the first xlsxwriter tutorial](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html) or the examples in [Working with data](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_data.html)

Comment: If you use Pandas you could use the [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) method to write the data to an `Excel` file. Pandas uses `xlsxwriter` internally